# Set text in the InputMethod

Tags: android, cursor, clipboard, android-input-method

I'm developing a new android app, I'm giving some parameters to a service, one of this is a string that I want to set in the inputmethod when it's displayed.

To make it clear, when the user is in this situation:
[image]

I want to change programmatically the text to input without having the reference of the edittext or whatever the cursor is set.

I don't know really how to do it. I should use the inputmethodmanager or maybe get an instance of the cursor?

Any idea how can I do this?

Hope my question is clear.
thanks

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand your question. Perhaps you could post some code of what you have tried?

Comment: So you want to set a default text in every possible text views in android? No, it is not possible.